# Problem with Subversion and Build event under Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I checked out 
http://code.google.com/p/flashdevelop/

In pre Build there is
SubWCRev "$(SolutionDir)\" "$(SolutionDir)FlashDevelop\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs.rev" "$(SolutionDir)FlashDevelop\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"

I changed SubWCRev to "c:...\SubWCRev.exe" because it's not in path env variable. But I got

"subwcrev ... exited with code 6."

Comment: Try adding the folder SubWCRev is in to your Environment Paths.
Code 6 looks to be that the folder it found is not under version control. Did you do an Export or a Checkout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 6 means "SVN Error" as seen in the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/src/SubWCRev/SubWCRev.cpp) of SubWCRev.

That means that the status couldn't be fetched for some reason.
Maybe one of the files is opened in another app, the folder is read/write protected, ...
Or maybe the version of SubWCRev is not the same as your svn client with which you checked out the working copy - in that case the wc format may not be the same.

Comment: I uninstalled everything and wanted to reinstall tortoisevsn 64 bits but when right-clicking I cannot see run as administrator ?

Comment: The error code can cover a lot of different things, but for me it began exiting with code 6 after i had some error in a update. I belive it was unable to use some internal repository file because of some other process. I fixed it by using the Clean Up command in tortuiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, "subwcrev ... exited with code 6." error occurred when I haven't added folders/files to the svn. After adding required folders/files to the SVN Repository this error is resolved.